# How to show tooltip using ASP.NET MVC 3 Chart Web Helper

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor, charts, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there any sample to show tooltip on chart generated by Chart Web Helper in ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor engine? I have to create and show child chart when user clicks on any point of parent chart. Please let me know how i can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Now, There is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking but my take on it is this...

This will show a page with a chart. When you click on the chart, it will open a new chart. Very basic but maybe enough to play around with.

Put this in your controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetRainfallChart()
    {
        var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
            .AddSeries(
                chartType: "bar",
                legend: "Chart",
                xValue: new[] { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri" },
                yValues: new[] { "23", "12", "13", "42", "22" })
            .Write();

        return null;
    }

    public ActionResult GetRainfallChart2()
    {
        var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
            .AddSeries(
                chartType: "pie",
                legend: "Another chart",
                xValue: new[] { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri" },
                yValues: new[] { "23", "12", "13", "42", "22" })
            .Write();

        return null;
    }
```

and this for your view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false
            });

            $("#chart").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <img id="chart" src="/Home/GetRainfallChart" alt="Chart tooltip" />

    <div id="dialog">
        <img src="/Home/GetRainfallChart2" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to show tooltip means if user mouse over the point of Mon in chart it should show 23 in your example and 12 for Tue.

Comment: gotcha... since these charts are rendered as images, I don't think this can be easily done. You could try and put an image map on it but I don't think it would be worth the effort. you could try one of the jquery charting products eg. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/gchart or http://www.jqplot.com/ (i haven't used these before but from what I can see, they are free options)

Answer (score 0):

There is another `Chart` class in `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`. It uses the same renderer, but lets you create charts from code more easily. This `Chart` has the built in function `GetHtmlImageMap`, which you can use to display tooltips for each of the data points. The view model would have both the image map and the image.

Unfortunately the `@Html.ImageFromByte` doesn't allow you to specify an image map, but you can work around this. Convert the graph image to base64 display it using raw html.

controller:

```
            System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart = // create your chart
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            chart.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            var vm = new YourViewModel
            {
                ChartBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer()),
                ChartHtmlMap = chart.GetHtmlImageMap("map")
            };
```

viewmodel:

```
        public string ChartBase64 { get; set; }
        public string ChartHtmlMap { get; set; }
```

cshtml:

```
    @Html.Raw("<img src=data:image/jpg;base64," + Model.ChartBase64 + " usemap=\"#map\">")
    @Html.Raw(Model.ChartHtmlMap)
```